# How to find all tables with the same (similar) name in Databricks SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Is there a sql query that can be used to find all of the tables in a Databricks instance for a given name?  Something like

```
select * from information_schema.tables where lower(table_name) like 'org%';
```

If there isn't a way to do this in sql, is there another way to do this?

It looks like Databricks doesn't have something like the "information_schema" or other meta data tables that other database management systems have, are there plans to add something like this in future releases (thing like "show tables()" are really inadequate for so many use cases including the one discussed here).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SHOW TABLES ... LIKE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-tables.html) command for that. Please note that in contrast to "regular LIKE", instead of using `%` you need to use `*`, and that by default matching is case insensitive, so you don't need to do `lower`. Another thing to remember - you either need to specify database name explicitly, or lookup will be done only for current database:

```sql
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'org*'; -- current database
SHOW TABLES IN another_db LIKE 'org*'; -- another database
```

Comment: Helpful, but still lacks a lot of the functionality that would be available with a meta data schema.  It would be *really* nice if Databricks added a meta data schema.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW TABLES [FROM | IN] db_name [LIKE 'pattern']
```

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-tables.html